# Aligning a sprite with a tilemap

Tags: unity, collision-detection, tilemap, grid

I'm trying to create a hybrid system for my Unity game. I want to use tilemap for collision and use sprites for the world.

I drew a sprite onto a 40x40 checkerboard grid as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCtW0.jpg). I wanted an easy way to create a collider for this without spending 30+ minutes hand placing box colliders and I decided to use a tilemap to place red tiles and use a tilemap collider for collision geometry and just hide the red tiles in-game.

Issue is, I have no clue how to align the checkerboard with the Unity tilemap grid.

[Here's a screenshot of the sprite in the unity editor with the tilemap grid visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otHh6.jpg)

If it isn't obvious, then the white lines is the grid for the tilemaps. The cellsize for each cell on the grid isn't the same size as the cells on the checkerboard pattern and I have no idea how to fix it.

The PPU (pixels per unit) of the sprite is 140. The PPU for the tileset tile(singular since there is literally only 1 tile in the entire tileset) is also 140. The checkerboard in paint.net is 40x40 and so is the tile. How can I get the cellsize of the grid in unity to match the cell size of the checkerboard.

Comment: If your checker squares are 40 pixels, is it safe to assume you tried a PPU of 40?